# I have been logged in from completely new browser, new installation of Linux

Tags: support, auto-login

I have installed Ubuntu after a while on my notebook, installed Chrome (but unfortunately ran Firefox - also untouched (but yes, logged in to Facebook)) and came to http://stackoverflow.com.

It has shown me `Welcome back genesis, you've been logged in`.

What is going on?

If I look into "my logins" on my profile, I see that last OpenID was used on 25th March.

Comment: It's part of the brand new, installed in your brain always-on cookie, that's--oh crap I'm not supposed to talk about that

Comment: And you didn't copy anything from your `/home` from the old system to the new system?

Comment: @Zord absolutely not

Comment: I first read that as `Welcome back genius, you've been logged in`.

Comment: I think it may be a facebook bug. My company has also written a cross-domain single sign-on system that offers a facebook connect option, and I was working on it today. During testing, I opened up one of our pages on a system that I've never loaded it on before, and it signed me in immediately (and I had been logged into facebook). I assumed I just mis-followed something and that I was just confused about something, but you offer corroborating evidence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome, eh?

Let me guess, you [signed in](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=165139) on both your machines with your Google account. Chrome probably synced your local storage from your first computer and Stack Overflow recognized you.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not the case - I haven't logged in to resync

Comment: Then my second guess is gonna have to be unicorn magic because some manner of browser sync is really the only plausible explanation I can think of.

Comment: WHOOOPS. Big mistake, big mistake. I have turned Firefox on, not Chrome. That's confusing even more

Comment: Just say it was magic...